# How to nicely print time difference in bash?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, printing

In my `bash` script, I want to print the time that my set of commands took to execute.

I'm doing this:

```
#!/bin/bash
start=$(date +%s)
./my-long-command.sh
./another-longcommand.sh
echo "Completed, in $(echo "$(date +%s) - ${start}" | bc)s"
```

It prints, for example:

```
Completed, in 450s
```

I want it to print milliseconds, or seconds, or minutes, or hours -- depending on the value. Also, I don't want to write a complex expression for `bc` in every script, where I need to print such a time difference. Are you aware of any `tdiff` command in Linux, which would enable this:

```
echo "Completed, in $(tdiff ${start})"
```

Please, don't suggest creating my own script for this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903239/how-can-i-calculate-time-elapsed-in-a-bash-script and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/387010/bash-calculate-the-time-elapsed-between-two-timestamps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [a builtin variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-SECONDS) for this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
./my-long-command.sh
./another-longcommand.sh
echo "Completed, in ${SECONDS}s"
```

> Please, don't suggest creating my own script for this.

Why not? It's not that complex:

```bash
tdiff() {
    if (($1 < 60)); then
        printf '%ds' "$1"
    elif (($1 < 60*60)); then
        printf '%dm' $(($1 / 60))
        tdiff $(($1 % 60))
    else
        printf '%dh' $(($1 / (60*60)))
        tdiff $(($1 % (60*60)))
    fi
}
```